# Display multi values field as html list

Tags: 7, views, theming, entities

In my content type I have two multi values fields for images and embedded videos. Those fields are displayed in view.

I wanted to display elements of these fields in carousel. I found [solution on google](http://ericlondon.com/adding-jquery-image-carousel-your-node-view), but this solution only works when I have more than one items in field.

I didn't manage to do it for one element in the field.

I want to display those fields (no matter if field has one or more items) in html list.

Could somebody give me any advice?

**[EDIT]**

I try similar solution to @Shoaib Nawaz answers, but because of memory problems I can display values only from $row object.

The part with data of embedded videos look like this:

```
   [node_data_field_video_field_video_embed] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [embed] => http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XnflHoDIwFk
                    [value] => XnflHoDIwFk
                    [provider] => youtube
                    [data] => a:6:{s:20:"emvideo_data_version";i:5;s:23:"emvideo_youtube_version";i:5;s:8:"duration";i:831;s:8:"playlist";i:0;s:9:"thumbnail";a:1:{s:3:"url";s:43:"http://img.youtube.com/vi/XnflHoDIwFk/0.jpg";}s:5:"flash";a:3:{s:3:"url";s:32:"http://youtube.com/v/XnflHoDIwFk";s:4:"size";s:4:"1011";s:4:"mime";s:29:"application/x-shockwave-flash";}}
                    [status] => 1
                    [version] => 5
                    [title] => 
                    [description] => 
                    [duration] => 831
                )
```

The part of images looks like:

```
[node_data_field_photos_field_photos_fid] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [fid] => 18515
                    [list] => 1
                    [data] => a:2:{s:3:"alt";s:30:"System stołów automatycznych";s:5:"title";s:0:"";}
                )
```

Screen with jcarousel with this stuff (worked only for fields with more than one items):

[image]

Now I need to find function to turn this data to html or code it all.

Comment: How you want to show your images and videos? What type of videos do you need embed code of you tube videos from url or id?

Comment: In html list, colorbox preset images or videos. I am adding videos by pasting url. I am adding screen how it should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do it with View field template. Edit your view and check for 'Theme information'. View will suggest some suitable field template according to your field and view's name. The most common template of fields is **views-view-field.tpl.php**

Other specific can be:

```
views-view-field--<my-field>.tpl.php,
views-view-field--<my-view>.tpl.php,
views-view-field--<my-view>--<my-field>.tpl.php,
views-view-field--<my-display>.tpl.php,
views-view-field--<my-display>--<my-field>.tpl.php,
views-view-field--<my-view>--<my-display>.tpl.php,
views-view-field--<my-view>--<my-display>--<my-field>.tpl.php
```

Here `<my-field>`, `<my-view>`, `<my-display>` are placeholders to replace actual field, view and display name.

Create any one of template in your active theme directory and
Try `print_r(get_defined_vars());` in your template to know available variables/values.

Comment: Thanks you this response, but because of memory problems I can display only $row values. Result of $row is in my edited question.

Comment: print_r(array_keys(get_defined_vars())); this first let you know what are variables available here. Then dig variables one by one. Have a try with $field(s) variable.

Comment: When I try to print $field which is probably what I want I am getting WSOD unfortunately

Comment: Edit settings.php for ini_set('memory_limit', '200M'); as WSOD id normally due to memory shortage.

Comment: Thanks, changing settings.php doesn't work, hope someone increase memory for me in php.ini